# Xbox 360 turns on but nothing happens after that

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I have an Xbox-360 which I only started using after a couple of years sitting in a box. When I turn it on the Xbox 360 symbol appears along with the Xbox sound. My remote flashes and after about 5 minutes it stops at player 1, then nothing happens. The Xbox isn't freezing it just doesn't proceed to Xbox home nor the game. I've unplugged everything 100 times and cleaned the Xbox and still nothing happens. It just won't proceed from the Xbox sign that appears when you turn it on.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment to ask a question, so this will have to do.

Are you getting any red rings on your console?
[Red Ring Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_technical_problems)

If not, is your 360's disk drive spinning?  You can usually hear it if your close enough, or feel it spool up.  If it isn't, it might be the DVD player itself.

If you DVD is spooling, it might be the laser that reads the disks.
What type of disks have you tried?  Games, DVDs, CDs, no disk?

It also could have a boot issue.  My best guess would be take it to GameStop or Geek Squad have them look at it.  If Geek Squad actually looks at it (it's been awhile since I've used them), they might charge you money to open the case.

Hopefully this offered a little bit of help.